# React Build failed on heroku deploy with the "Can't resolve...." error

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern

```
       Creating an optimized production build...
       
        daisyUI components 1.25.3  https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui
         ✔︎ Including:  base, components, themes[22], utilities
         
       Failed to compile.
       
   Failed to compile.
   
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../components/frontPage/CategoryList' in '/tmp/build_5fc1809c/client/src/pages/FrontPages'

       
       
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.v8tuj/_logs/2022-01-28T00_19_24_843Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! onlinemenu@0.0.1 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the onlinemenu@0.0.1 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.v8tuj/_logs/2022-01-28T00_19_24_861Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

That is the error, build locally works fine, changing components folder and restructuring did nothing except the error changed to

```
   src/FrontPages/Home.jsx
   Syntax error: Unexpected token (2:0) (2:undefined)
```

also I update the paths for each individual component.

I am losing hope at this moment at Heroku because it's getting exponentially harder to deploy and test my app the more I develop it.

What it doesn't understand from ../../components/blah/blah/blah?

Please help or tell me where else I can deploy more easily and consistently a MERN app. Because as far as it goes everything looks difficult with way underdocumented instructions online or at the cloud service provider.

File Tree in src folder:

```
src
 ┣ actions
 ┃ ┗ categoriesActions.js
 ┣ components
 ┃ ┣ dashboard
 ┃ ┣ frontPage
 ┃ ┃ ┣ CatalogueProduct.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ CatalogueSubcategory.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ CategoryCard.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ CategoryList.jsx
 ┃ ┣ layout
 ┃ ┃ ┣ assets
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ spinner.gif
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ spinner2.gif
 ┃ ┃ ┣ dashboard
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ DashHeader.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ DashNavBar.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ frontpages
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Footer.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Header.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ Navbar.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ Spinner.jsx
 ┃ ┗ shared
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Alert.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ InfoButton.jsx
 ┣ constants
 ┃ ┗ categoriesConstants.js
 ┣ pages
 ┃ ┣ Dashboard
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Dashboard.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ DashIndex.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ NotFound.jsx
 ┃ ┗ FrontPages
 ┃ ┃ ┣ About.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Catalogue.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Frontpage.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ Home.jsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ NotFound.jsx
 ┣ reducers
 ┃ ┗ categoriesReducers.js
 ┣ styles
 ┃ ┣ alert.css
 ┃ ┣ card.css
 ┃ ┗ navbar.css
 ┣ App.css
 ┣ App.js
 ┣ index.css
 ┣ index.js
 ┗ store.js
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you developing locally on Windows? Do the paths you're using in your code and the paths on the filesystem differ, e.g. `FrontPages` vs. `frontpages` vs. `Frontpages`?

Comment: They do differ and everything is checked if it is at the correct path. For example there are two front pages folders in the src on in the components folder and one in the pages folder. I pay a lot of attention in the folder structure as the project is a little complicated in that part. I have already a deployed MEN stack of it, I’m just trying to add react to make it more fluid and alive.

Comment: They _differ?_ Maybe you misunderstood my question (and you didn't answer whether you're using Windows). By default, Windows uses a case-preserving-but-not-enforcing filesystem. As a result, if you have a file at `Foo/Bar.jsx` and refer to it as `foo/bar.jsx` in your code it will probably work on Windows. But it will _not_ work on Heroku (or anywhere else with a sane filesystem), where those are considered to be different paths.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot. I do use windows but take a look at my folder tree. Am I missing something? I added it to the question above. Sorry...

Comment: I moved all the pages from their subfolders to the page folder and now the build is successful and the app is deployed normally to heroku. So what is the problem using ../../ to times back in paths? While when importing actions from a deeply nested component there is no problem whatsoever? Ex. import { listCategories } from '../../actions/categoriesActions'